# How to set up Windows PCs on a Mac server

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, osx-server

I have a Mac server that has Mac PCs connected to it, and Windows PCs connected to it as well and I am unable to let Windows users log into the server via their PC. How would I go permitting access to the Windows PC user accounts which are running Windows 7?

Edit: I am using OS X Lion not sure of the exact version but it is Lion and on a Mac Pro I think, if relevant.

Comment: What version of Mac server are you running?

Comment: There is too much here we have to assume -- what have you tried? Are you trying to get the windows to log on using the Mac box as a directory server? Are you just trying to get them onto a file share? What service is the server running that you are trying to use?

Comment: @NReilingh I haven't been able to try much but it won't connect straight forward as I've done with computers on AD for windows. I want to be able to authenticate users to login to the Windows 7 computers where the users and info is stored on the Mac server. I would also like the users on the Windows computers to connect to File shares on the server. The server stores local accounts, email, web hosting, and connects to few Macs and Windows PCs.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it really sounds like you don't know what you're getting yourself into -- I would advise finding someone to help you design a better infrastructure based on your specific needs.

Windows 7 is not able to natively authenticate to the OS X Server Open Directory. You will need to choose one of the solutions on [this support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4945?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) to work around.

Setting up a file share is much easier -- it just needs to be available using the [SMB protocol](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5884).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am going to look at pGina and SMB and when I set it up will let you know. Thanks.